# Effecient dataframe lookup and extraction

Tags: pandas, dataframe, performance

I want to calculate the centroid by x,y,z mean of 8 coordinates. The element ID refers to the cube whereas the Node ID refers to the spheres on the cube. I have one dataframe containing the Element ID and the ID on the connected nodes. In another dataframe I have the Node ID and its coordinates. What is the most efficient way to for each element ID look up the adjacent nodes coordinates and based on these calculate the centroid of the cube?

Datastructure of Dataframe containing element ID and node ID

```
        Element ID  Node 1  Node 2  Node 3  ...  Node 5  Node 6  Node 7  Node 8
0           856395  764524  768124  767621  ...  766463  768139  767613  767612
1           856396  764524  767551  767621  ...  764525  767491  767622  768125
2           856397  764525  767491  767622  ...  764526  767431  767623  768126
3           856398  764526  767431  767623  ...  764527  767371  767624  768127
4           856399  764527  767371  767624  ...  764528  767311  767625  768128
```

Datastructure of Dataframe containing Node ID and node coordinates

```
        Node ID         X         Y         Z
0        764525  0.342972 -0.104031  6.499699
1        764526  0.342976 -0.104033  6.514697
2        764527  0.342979 -0.104034  6.529694
3        764528  0.342980 -0.104034  6.544691
4        764529  0.342981 -0.104035  6.559689
```

[image]

This works but is really ugly and slow :-(

```
append1 = pd.merge(df_element_ids_nodes,df_node_ids_coordinates, left_on="Node 1", right_on="Node ID")
append2 = pd.merge(append1,df_node_ids_coordinates, left_on="Node 2", right_on="Node ID")
append3 = pd.merge(append2,df_node_ids_coordinates, left_on="Node 3", right_on="Node ID")
append4 = pd.merge(append3,df_node_ids_coordinates, left_on="Node 4", right_on="Node ID")
append5 = pd.merge(append4,df_node_ids_coordinates, left_on="Node 5", right_on="Node ID")
append6 = pd.merge(append5,df_node_ids_coordinates, left_on="Node 6", right_on="Node ID")
append7 = pd.merge(append6,df_node_ids_coordinates, left_on="Node 7", right_on="Node ID")
append8 = pd.merge(append7,df_node_ids_coordinates, left_on="Node 8", right_on="Node ID")

print(append8)

df_results = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ElementId", "X", "Y", "Z"])
for index, row in append8.iterrows():
    centroid_x = (row[10] + row[14] + row[18] + row[22] + row[26] + row[30] + row[34] + row[38])/8
    centroid_y = (row[11] + row[15] + row[19] + row[23] + row[27] + row[31] + row[35] + row[39])/8
    centroid_z = (row[12] + row[16] + row[20] + row[24] + row[28] + row[32] + row[36] + row[40])/8
    Element_ID = row[0]
    df_results = df_results.append({"ElementId": int(Element_ID), "X": centroid_x, "Y": centroid_y, "Z": centroid_z}, ignore_index=True)


print(df_results)
```

Answer (score 0):

One quite efficient way is to perform a dataframe join of the dataframe. A join should sort the ID and perform a dichotomy on the IDs of de dataframe containing the nodes ID for each needed ID appearing in the main dataframe. This operation is done in `O(n log n)` time. In the best case, it can hash the node indices to do that in `O(1)` time. Here are two examples:

```py
# Case 1 -- discard the 'Node ID' field:
elementDataframe.set_index('Node ID').join(nodeDataframe.set_index('Node ID'))

# Case 2 -- do not discard the field and is simpler to use:
elementDataframe.merge(nodeDataframe, on='Node ID')
```

If the node IDs are contiguous (and so sorted), then there is a much faster solution: you can get a node ID using a direct access (like a *lookup table*) using `nodeDataframe.iloc[nodeIndices-startingId]` where `startingId` is 764525 in your example and `nodeIndices` is a Numpy array containing the node IDs (eg. `elementDataframe['Node 1']`. This operation is done in `O(n)` time and should be faster than a basic join. To be more precise, the code should be the following in your case:

```py
nodeDataframe.iloc[elementDataframe['Node ID']-nodeDataframe['Node ID'].min()]
```

Comment: Can you write an example - Im not able to convert your recommendations into code

Comment: I modified the answers to add more information.